# open ms doc,docx or image file in browser in c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, browser, docx

I have developed the asp.net mvc application. my one form have the file upload control. so in details view i want to implement the facility to view the uploaded document in browser itself. it **should not ask for download** and should not open MS office instance to open document. its a user req. It should opens in view mode in browser itself. what code i have to do ? I am using C# as language.

Answer (score 0):

It is not straight forward. For images you can use `<img>`tag and link to the location in server where you saved the uploaded image. That should work.

However ASFAIK showing the doc/docx things in web page itself is not possible. You will have to employ some third party control to achieve that. Search google to find such controls. May come at a cost.

Comment: Yes pradeep you are right, but if you have gmail account and if you get any mail with attachment of docx, there is a option as "View" and "Download". If you say View then it opens the document in the new tab of browser. how this is possible? what have to do to implement this ?

Comment: I found this http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html which can help you. But to use this your document should be in public domain and that might not be feasible for you. Google achieves it in a different ways. You can try looking for some third party controls.

Comment: very nice pradeep, but I can not trust on third party software.but, is this possible to read the document and generate its HTML view source and show it to page. is this possible ?